# VBA Excel Convert Date Time to Text

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to convert a date time to text.

Example: 10/22/2019 2:10 PM should be converted to 43760.59028. I know how to do this if I was trying to convert a cell in a spreadsheet, but I'm trying to convert a date time variable.

I've tried: `vdate = Format(CDate("10/22/2019 2:10 PM"), "@")`

I end up with a string rather than the text conversion to a number.

How do I convert a date or date time and store the value in a variable?

Comment: `vdate = cdbl(CDate("10/22/2019 2:10 PM"))`

Comment: Awesome, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Format` yields a `String`, you don't want that.

Declare `vdate` as a `Double`:

```
Dim vdate As Double
```

Now this will work:

```
vdate = CDate("10/22/2019 2:10 PM")
```

...but that's an implicit type conversion from `Date` to `Double`; you can make it explicit:

```
vdate = CDbl(CDate("10/22/2019 2:10 PM"))
```

...as [Scott mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58512077/vba-excel-convert-date-time-to-text#comment103351582_58512077)

Answer (score 0):

this example may be help you

```
Sub convert_date2txt()
     Dim theRange as Range
     Set theRange = Selection
     Dim sDate As String
     For Each theCell In theRange
         sDate=Format(theCell,"dd/mm/yyyy")
         theCell.Value = sDate
         theCell.NumberFormat="@"
     Next
End Sub
```